# Populating a star-schema from a single staging table.

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

What is the best way of populating a star-schema from a single staging table. 
The dataload is in number of millions of rows and the star-schema is one fact table with 10 associated dimension tables.

**Scenario 1.** Doing sequential inserts into dimensions first and afterwards a big insert into the fact table where I join the staging table with the updated dimension tables. My biggest concern here is the locking that might occur due to the concurrent inserts into dimension/fact tables due to the huge amount of data.

**Scenario 2.** Splitting the data load into smaller batches (10k rows) and looping through the entire staging table and inserting the batches in the same manner as described in *Scenarion 1.* The problem I'm seeing here is looping through a big table with cursors. Plus in case one of the batches fails to insert the data I would need to rollback changes for all of the inserts done previously.

**Scenario 3.** Write a big *INSERT ALL* statement and lock the star-schema for the whole duration of the insert. Moreover to the locking problems I would have a complex insert statment that will have to hold all of the business logic for the insert statements (a nightmare to debug and maintain)

Comment: What kind of "locks" are you concerned about?  With row-level locking, a normal insert should not affect anything else.

Comment: The fact table has indexes on the keys. And I assume that there will be locks during the insert time.

Comment: Oracle only locks the rows it modifies. So there is no exclusive lock on insert except on the rows being inserted (which of course are [invisible to other transactions until commit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#BABEIHGJ)). Also in Oracle [write don't block read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#CNCPT88970), ever. The shared locks on the table structures won't block other readers or writers (these locks only prevent DDL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE in 11g Release 2(!)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS233

Works fine to separate a big table in smaller chunks and it lets you define the grade of parallelism very easyly. Don't use parallel hints or insert append inside the processing of the chunks though.

Your assumption that you can load the dimension tables without problems seem me too optimistic. In my experience you must cater for the situation that not all informations for the dimension data are valid at load time.